# Angular testing: mocking a service throwing an error makes other tests failing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I've already read other two questions about it here, but they didn't help at all
I have 3 test, where I mock a service specifying the return value as `throwError` (from rxjs)

The code in the component:

```
this.userService.resetPassword(resetReq)
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          this.setSubmittingState(form, false);
          this.submitErrorMsg = 'Something wrong happend';
          if (err) {
            switch (true) {
              case err.status === 400:
                this.submitErrorMsg = 'Something in your URL might be wrong';
                break;
            }
          }
          // if no return would be set here, the first callback of the
          // subscription would be performed
          return throwError(err);
        })
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.router.navigate([this.appRoutes.HOME]);
      }, (err) => { /* whatever */ });
```

Code in the test:

```
service.resetPassword.and.returnValue(throwError({ error: null, status: 400, message: '' }));
```

on Karma I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught [object Object] thrown` (this message thrown under a different test)

and on the console I'm getting `Uncaught {error: null, status: 400, message: ""}`

Does anyone know how to sort it?

Comment: We can't see where `service.resetPassword` is being used, so it's impossible to say; please give a [mre]. As far as your test double goes, that is the correct way to return an observable that emits an error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe does it help what I added?

Comment: `return throwError(err)` - does anything handle the re-emitted error? Where's the *test* that's showing an error.

Comment: Well it's handled in the **pipe** with **catchError**

Comment: No, I mean the `throwError` *in that `catchError`*, where you *re*-emit it.

Comment: No, it's not anywhere

Comment: Then does that explain why you're seeing an unhandled error?

Comment: Can give me an example, how you'd fix that issue?

Comment: It depends on your context. If you're purposefully re-emitting the error because that's part of the service's API, then the test needs to handle it. If it's not required, maybe catching it in the pipe should be the end of it?

Comment: the **return throwError** is there for stopping the success callback in the subscribe to be performed, but even adding a second callback which manage errors in observables, I'm getting the same error

Comment: Again, please give a [mre].

Comment: I edited the main code, but I don't know what you mean by "minimal reproducible example", see if that helps

Comment: Please read the linked article, it explains exactly what that means. We should be able to copy-paste some code to recreate the same issue locally, and be able to see in the question exactly what the expected and actual outputs are.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it returning `empty()` instead of `throwError(error)` in the component